# Receber parâmetro e dependendo do valor executar uma procedure específica

Tags: sql-server, asp

Tenho um sistema em Asp Clássico, e preciso executar uma procedure SQL Server específica, de acordo com um parâmetro que o sistema recebe de um form.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
if tipoagenda = 1 then
   ssql1 = "exec VerificaDataDisponivel"
elseif tipoagenda = 2 then
   ssql1 = "exec VerificaDataDisponivel_Pedido"
else 
   ssql1 = "exec VerificaDataDisponivel_Reagenda"
end if
```

ou assim:

```
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
if tipoagenda = 1 then 
   .CommandText = "HorarioDisponivelHomolog"
elseif tipoagenda = 2 then
   .CommandText = "HorarioDisponivelHomolog_Pedido"
else 
   .CommandText = "HorarioDisponivelHomolog_Reagenda"
end
```

Mas dá erro dizendo: 'if' esperado na linha 31 end'

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: uso sem o `then`, no final vc manda `exec(ssql1)` que ele vai rodar a query que vc gerou!

Comment: tirei o then e apareceu o erro: 'Then' esperado

Comment: [Aqui](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1484/stored-procedure-dinamica.aspx) tem um bom exemplo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria uma procedure unica e executa essa seleção dentro do SQl server mesmo.

declare @tipoagenda int

set @tipoagenda = 1

if @tipoagenda = 1 begin
   print 'exec VerificaDataDisponivel'
 end
else if  @tipoagenda = 2 begin
    print 'exec VerificaDataDisponivel_Pedido'
end
else 
    print 'exec VerificaDataDisponivel_Reagenda'